# What is the cleanest way to create a GUIless application?

Tags: android, service

Good Morning.

I have a question about how to create an application without GUI. It should start when the user pushes the icon. Reading other posts, seems that the natural way of doing this would be a Service.

Since the app has no GUI, it makes no sense to add any Activity. For this reason, the Service has to be unbinded. So, if there is no component calling `startService`, and no external component is sending an intent, ¿how does the service start?

Is there any attribute in the manifest to achieve this? Or maybe extending Application and using `onCreate` to start the service?

Thanks.

UPDATES:
-There's no way to start a Service in the same app without an Intent. Other options would be autostart or Broadcast receivers, but these don't fit my requirements.
-Tried a test app without Activities, and the icon isn't even showing in the launcher. Don't know the reason of this, maybe related to the manifest not having a LAUNCHER activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list of applications shown in the Android launcher is basically the list of all **activities** in the system that have a `LAUNCHER` intent filter:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

If you put this intent filter on a `<service>`, it will not work (just tried). Thus, the only way to do what you want to do is through an `Activity`. I think the cleanest way is something like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Intent service = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    startService(service);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service started.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    finish();
}
```

The user will not see anything except a small message at the bottom of the screen saying "Service started." that will automatically disappear in a couple of seconds. It's clean **and** user-friendly.

Comment: By the moment it seems that this is the only thing that works. Also tried using the Application object's `onCreate`, but without any Activity there's no icon showing in the launcher, and the Service does not start.

Comment: The `Application`'s `onCreate` is called every time your process is created. Because no components are there to start the process, the `onCreate` method is not called.

Answer (score 0):

The service is started either when somebody calls `startService()` or when somebody calls `bindService()`. Note that if service is only started via `bindService()` it will be automatically stopped when Activity either explicitly unbinds from it or is destroyed (and it was the only binder).

You can declare [`BOOT_COMPLETED_ACTION`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) broadcast receiver in your `AndroidManifest.xml` and start your service on system boot. But you service will only start on next device reboot. And there are some issues with applications without activities and this broadcast event in Android 3.1. More info can be found [here](http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/05/boot-completed-regression.html).

In general, its good to have at least one activity in your application, even if your primary component is service. This activity will start the service when user launches it, and also may expose some ability to configure the service behavior.

---

Example of activity that starts service:

```
public class ServiceStarterActivity extends Activity
{       
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       

        startService(new Intent(this, ServiceA.class));
        finish();
    }    
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've read about traslucent activities used to launch services, but I'd like to launch the service in a cleaner way if possible. And it should not autostart on system boot, only at user request.

Comment: No, I don't mean translucent activities. How exactly user makes his "request" if you do not have activities?

Comment: Pushing the application icon.

Comment: Users won't get any feedback when the icon is pressed, which can suggest that the application icon doesn't do anything

Comment: @DEiE I don't mind about feedback by now. I'll take on that later, it can be solved with  Toasts or running the service on foreground. BTW, there's no icon if there are no activities :(

Comment: And how will your icon appear in Application Launcher? You have to have Activity for this, and your activity can start service and finish itself. I've updated the answer with an example.